# How to use selenium-webdriver with chrome 94?

Tags: node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver

In node.js, I install selenium chrome driver using

```
npm install selenium-webdriver
```

but then when I run it, it says

```
(node:20708) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: SessionNotCreatedError: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 91
Current browser version is 94.0.4606.61 with binary path C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
```

since I have Chrome 94

How can I get it to work?

Comment: Use matching Chromedriver version (major version should match so V94): https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=94.0.4606.61/

Comment: But this is node.js, is there a npm command for it?

Comment: You don't really have to install it... just set path to it.  (You can do that using an environment variable i.e. PATH, or passing the path to the webdriver...  maybe include your webdriver initialization code for more detailed instructions.)  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Tools_and_testing/Cross_browser_testing/Your_own_automation_environment